# How to launch Jenkins as an Admin without credentials/authentication?

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, devops

I skipped creating users and launched Jenkins as an Admin user for the first time after installation. Now, when I launch Jenkins the second time, it keep prompting me to enter username and password; how to get rid of this?

[image]

after giving invalid credentials,
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a solution for this.

- Go to `/Users/prashanthsams/.jenkins/`

[image]

- Open `config.xml` and remove the highlighted security tags

[image]

```
  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
    <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
  </authorizationStrategy>
  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm">
    <disableSignup>true</disableSignup>
    <enableCaptcha>false</enableCaptcha>
  </securityRealm>
```

- It works without authentication

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal, then type command:

```
vi /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
```

you will see something like this:

```
fee1427b9ac74560b91c52d0ea7329b7
```

For later steps:

default username: `admin`

default password: `fee1427b9ac74560b91c52d0ea7329b7`

Reference: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging#Logging-MacOSX

If you use Linux, see: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging#Logging-Linux

If you use Windows, see: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging#Logging-Windows

Comment: This screen comes only on initial setup

Comment: No, the admin and the default generated password doesn't work on later steps; I tried it on myself.

Comment: edit: sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword get password and then admin the shown password from command

Answer (score 0):

When you skipped user creation during 1st install. the Password is which you pasted during install in previous steps.

cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
it will show you your password

314d395a479a413f9265f36ff60fe953

that is the admin password.